# SQL to count turnover and group by month (please check)

Tags: sql, group-by, calc

I have three tables and I need to calculte turnover for John Smith in year 2015 divided by months.

```
                   OrderItems
                   ------------       Orders
Products           OrderItem_ID       ------
----------         Order_ID   <--->   Order_ID
Product_ID  <--->  Product_ID         Type
Name               Quantity           Date
Category           UnitPrice          Customer
```

The tables are connected by Order_ID & Order_ID (tabs OrderItems and Orders) and then by Product_IDs (tabs Products and OrderItems). I guess I don't need tab Products anyway.

```
Orders (Order_ID INT, Type INT, Date DATETIME, Customer VARCHAR)
OrderItems (OrderItem_ID INT, Order_ID INT, Product_ID INT, Quantity INT, UnitPrice MONEY)
Products (Product_ID INT, Name VARCHAR, Category VARCHAR)
```

---

I have been dozens and dozens minutes googling and knowledge refreshing because it is a long while since I have used SQL for the last time.

I wrote this query but totally I am not sure. Can you check it please?

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.quantity * a.price) AS 'turnover',
    DATEPART(month, a.date) AS 'month'
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        Quantity.OrderItems AS 'quantity',
        UnitPrice.OrderItems AS 'price',
        Date.Orders AS 'date',
        Customer.Orders AS 'customer'
    FROM Orders
    JOIN Orders 
        ON OrderItems.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31
        AND customer = 'John Smith'
) a
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Thank you very much

*//corrected one minor typo in code*

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: try running your inner query- it shouldn't compile.  You need to join `orders` to `orderitems`, not `orders` again.

Comment: also, your `group by` isn't going to work referencing your alias `month`.  You'll need to `group by` your `datepart` function.  It might be easier to understand if you return your month `datepart` in your inner query.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot compile it. It is offline exercise in generic SQL :-( It looks easily but... So I will join table like this JOIN OrdersItems `ON Orders.Order_ID = OrderItems.Order_ID` and group by `DATEPART(month, a.date)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `Orders` to `OrderItems`

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.quantity * a.price) AS 'turnover',
    DATEPART(month, a.date) AS 'month'
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        OI.Quantity AS 'quantity',
        OI.UnitPrice AS 'price',
        O.Date AS 'date',
        O.Customer AS 'customer'
    FROM Orders O
    INNER JOIN OrderItems OI
        ON O.Order_ID = OI.Order_ID
    WHERE
        O.date BETWEEN 2015-01-01 and 2015-12-31
        AND O.customer = 'John Smith'
) a
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, a.date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(month, a.date)
```